# facebooks sharedSession returning "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to activate cookies via the facebook login so it doesnt always depend on the session being there but whenever I set `sharedSession` to true I get a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error page.. Is this the way I'm suppose to make it so the facebook login uses cookies? I'm using the newest code on github for the facebook SDK (downloaded a freshy today) -> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

I'm not using the javascript SDK. and all of the coding below is fired before any headers are sent out. If I take the `sharedSession` out, it logs me in correctly, but it doesnt store a cookie with the info needed.

Heres the coding I'm using

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $Sets['facebook']['appId'],
    'secret' => $Sets['facebook']['appSecret'],
'sharedSession' => true,
//  'trustForwarded' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user){
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
// the user is logged into facebook
if($user){
    // I register them on my website..
    // and then send them to the index page
    header('Location: /index.php'); 
} else {
    // they are not registered through facebook
    if(isset($_GET['error'])){
            // this happens when an error is found
        die($_GET['error'].' error');
//      header("Location: /login/?error=".urlencode($_GET['error']));
        exit;
    } else {
            // send to facebook to log them in.
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($Sets['facebook']['scope_array']);
//      die('sending to '.$loginUrl);
        header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
        exit;
    }
}
```

You can see I put the `die()` function before any redirection there, this was for debugging on my end to see if I can figure out where it was failing, but it seems to happen after the user is returned to the website.. I also tried the trustForward => true, but that didnt fix it..

all I'm after is to be able to have the user logged in for a longer period of time, without having to login through facebook everytime they visit the website.

Whats happening is the user is stuck in a loop trying to log into facebook being redirected between facebook and my website because the user is never verified. Again, this ONLY happens when I set `'sharedSession' => true`

I'm trying to get the facebook sdk to store a cookie from my website onto the persons  computer that tries to login but no cookie is being set.

Answer (score 0):

I get confused by your question. what do you want to achieve:

1) If you want to set store your facebook user_id to cookie, you don't have to do anything. when the oauth process is completed facebook redirect to your "redirect_uri" url, the cookie is set by facebook to a cookie value:  fbsr_xxxx (xxxx is your appId)

2) If you want to keep user logged in longer time, you need to set your own session value to determine if the user is logged in or not. in other word, after the facebook oauth flow, your user login status has nothing to do with your facebook session.

BTW:  $Users->loginWithOauth, this function has no definition, what's this function for?

Comment: I'm trying to do 1) set the facebook cookie. Right now in my script with the code posted above, no cookie is geting set when the user logs in. This is using the most recent version of facebook php sdk on github. 
and `$Users->loginWithOauth` is my script registering the user..

Comment: your oauth process is not very clear, you should first follow facebook server side authentication flow to get code; after user authorized your app, facebook will call for the callback page, which is the script you posted; you can run whatever login logic at this step. Again, facebook cookie (fbsr_xxxx) is set by facebook , not by you. please refer to the article https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/, hope this is helpful

Comment: I updated the initial question some. I'm using -> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk which is recommended by facebook. I'm following the same practice as the example login page -> https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php to log the user in. Once a user is confirmed by facebook after accepting everything the user is registered fine on my website but no cookie is being set. Thats when I found that we should use `'sharedSession' => true` in the config for facebooks class, and thats when I get stuck in a redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

the reason is the required permission not granted so eventually it goes to facebook search for the token and comes back.

check for the permission you need.